# architecture of multitouch in flash on linux OS

Tags: linux, flash, multi-touch

1. does flash support multitouch in Linux OS?
2. how flash receives multitouch events from Linux OS?

if could you provide answers or drop links on information that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

[Multi-touch article at Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/multitouch_gestures.html) says that multi-touch is not supported on Linux. But since then people have integrated multi-touch support into the OS: [1](http://www.lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/index.html), [2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-touchpad/), [3](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/). You should read the articles above.

Flash natively works with multi-touch input through TouchEvent events. [This article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/multitouch_gestures.html) has a good explanation of how to use gestures and raw touch events. At least that's how multi-touch works on Windows 7 and devices.